# Adapter not set: default. Did you forget to setup?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, datamapper

I'm getting the same error when I execute my test in Rspec. DataMapper::RepositoryNotSetupError: Adapter not set: default. Did you forget to setup? I don't understand this error because I've set up Datamapper as it says in Datamapper webpage. I show you my code

vip_client-spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-postgres-adapter'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..', 'models', 'vip_client.rb')

describe VipClient do
  before {
    DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
  }
  describe "#insert_into_database" do
    it "inserts clients into database from an array of hashes" do
      list_clients = [
       {name: "David", birthday: "13-12-1985", email: "daviddsrperiodismo@gmail.com"},
       {name: "Javier", birthday: "05-05-1985", email: "javier@gmail.com"}
      ]
      VipClient.insert_into_database(list_clients)
      expect(VipClient.all.count).to eq(2)
    end
  end
end
```

vip_client.rb

```
class VipClient
  include ::DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, Text
  property :birthday, Date
  property :email, Text  

  def self.insert_into_database(list_clients)
  end

end
```

app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'
require 'roo'
require 'pony'

# HELPERS
require './helpers/code'
require './helpers/check_birthday_users'
require './helpers/excel_parser'

# MODELS
require './models/vip_client.rb'
require './models/invitations.rb'

include Code
include CheckUsers

DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://david:123456@localhost/usersmareta')
DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
```

And my gemfile is this

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'pg'
gem 'roo'
gem 'data_mapper'
gem 'dm-postgres-adapter'
gem 'pony'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rack-test'
  gem 'rspec'
end
```

As I've said. when I do rspec the console gives me this:

```
Failure/Error: DataMapper.finalize.auto_upgrade!
     DataMapper::RepositoryNotSetupError:
       Adapter not set: default. Did you forget to setup?
```

Comment: So try put `DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://david:123456@localhost/usersmareta')` string to `vip_client-spec.rb` into before section.

Comment: Thank you¡¡ That has worked fine. I thoug puting the setup inside app.rb was enough.